# Update Magento2 Checkout layout

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout, uicomponent

I am trying to update my checkout layout to use two columns, so the checkout fields are in the left column and the cart summary is in the right column.

In my checkout_index_index.xml, I have created two containers like:

```
<container htmlTag="div" htmlClass="checkout-main col-md-6">

</container>
<container htmlTag="div" htmlClass="checkout-aside col-md-6">

</container>
```

I am unsure how I can move the elements/items within the onepage.phtml into the correct columns?

Can anyone please advise how it is possible to update the checkout layout?

> checkout_index_index.xml

http://cnhv.co/1bq62

Comment: Did you find way how to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override your **checkout_index_index.xml** with below path:

```
magento/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout checkout_index_index.xml
```